# How to get rid of back pages on template for InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, template

I downloaded a template to use in InDesign, and it looks like it comes with both the front and back pages, like a booklet. (Left and right on the screen, each "side" is 8.5" by 11". How do I get rid of the back page, so that each page I make as you scroll down is independent of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In File > Document Setup, uncheck the "Facing Pages" option.  You should then be able to view the document one page at a time instead of covers and spreads.